# MongoDB: how to find out how many objects were skipped in query

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I'm running MongoDB v.2-4-4-pre- under Linux. I use simple find() operation with "skip" parameter to select some elements from my DB.

Is there any way to find out how many objects were skipped by my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It skips the the number of objects that YOU provide as an argument to the `skip()`. [Example from here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/skip/)

```
db.article.aggregate(
    { $skip : 5 }
);
```

> This operation skips the first 5 documents passed to it by the
>   pipeline. $skip has no effect on the content of the documents it
>   passes along the pipeline.

EDIT #1

Based on your comment, I believe you need to execute the [count command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/count/).

Comment: It CAN skip as many documents, as I passed. But if I used skip=5, there is no guarantee, that 5 elements were skipped. For example, it can skip only 3 (If there were only 3 items satisfying the criteria of selection).